# HTML Page not displaying using Python Socket Programming

Tags: python, sockets, http, network-programming

I'm trying to learn socket programming with python, and I've created a simple webserver, and I can connect to it in my browswer. I've opened an html file and send it, but it's not displaying in the browswer.

**My simple webserver**

```
import socket
import os

# Standard socket stuff:
host = ''
port = 8080
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(5) 

# Loop forever, listening for requests:
while True:
    csock, caddr = sock.accept()
    print("Connection from: " + str(caddr))
    req = csock.recv(1024)  # get the request, 1kB max
    print(req)
    # Look in the first line of the request for a move command
    # A move command should be e.g. 'http://server/move?a=90'
    filename = 'static/index.html'
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        csock.sendall(str.encode("""HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n""",'iso-8859-1'))
        csock.sendall(str.encode('Content-Type: text/html\n', 'iso-8859-1'))
        csock.send(str.encode('\n'))
        csock.sendall(str.encode(""+l+"", 'iso-8859-1'))
        print('Sent ', repr(l))
        l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()

    csock.close()
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the body</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm very new at this, so I'm probably just missing a very minute details, but I'd love some help on getting the html file to correctly display in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your script works fine by the way.
Maybe you need to check the `filename` value.

> note: little change to make sure all strings on html file sent.

```
import socket
import os

# Standard socket stuff:
host = ''
port = 8080
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(5) 

# Loop forever, listening for requests:
while True:
    csock, caddr = sock.accept()
    print("Connection from: " + str(caddr))
    req = csock.recv(1024)  # get the request, 1kB max
    print(req)
    # Look in the first line of the request for a move command
    # A move command should be e.g. 'http://server/move?a=90'
    filename = 'static/index.html'
    f = open(filename, 'r')

    csock.sendall(str.encode("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n",'iso-8859-1'))
    csock.sendall(str.encode('Content-Type: text/html\n', 'iso-8859-1'))
    csock.send(str.encode('\r\n'))
    # send data per line
    for l in f.readlines():
        print('Sent ', repr(l))
        csock.sendall(str.encode(""+l+"", 'iso-8859-1'))
        l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()

    csock.close()
```

Result on browser

[image]